# Combobox datasource got changed on selected index changed event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a combobox(cboDepartment) in my winform application. I am facing some unacceptable behavior of my combobox. Following is Selected changed event for this.

```
private void cboDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int comboboxCount=cboDepartment.Items.Count;
   int senderCount=(sender as ComboBox).Items.Count;
}
```

this is my only combobox in my form and this combobox has binded to a BindingSource which contains 3 items initially. On form loads this binding source add 12 new entries so it contains 15 items now. Now in above event when i am getting value in variable **comboboxCount** it is showing 3 and the **senderCount** is giving value 15.

I stuck to find why both variables giving different values.

Comment: Like you, I demand that all my controls exhibit only acceptable behavior and no less.  Controls that cannot meet this standard are asked to leave and play on forms with less stringent requirements :)

Comment: **Can't reproduce your problem**